# How to get the same session across subdomains in grails

Tags: tomcat, grails, subdomain, session-cookies

I have a single app handling multiple subdomains such as

- sub1.domain.com
- sub2.domain.com
- www.domain.com
- domain.com

The user can switch across these subdomains when using the app. When this happens the session is not shared across these subdomains. I use tomcat as the server for development and on production.

I am trying to make the shared sessions work in development first. On reading up, found that the way to achieve this in tomcat is:

```
<Context sessionCookiePath="/" sessionCookieDomain=".domain.com">
```

Is there a way I can set this in tomcat in the development environment?

I tried the below code in _Events.groovy, without success:

```
eventConfigureTomcat = {tomcat ->
    def context = tomcat.addContext("","/")
    context.setSessionCookieDomain(".domain.com")
    context.setSessionCookiePath("/")
}
```

I get the error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: addChild:  Child name '' is not unique

I assume what I need is an equivalent of the below code (Which cannot work since there is no getContext method):

```
eventConfigureTomcat = {tomcat ->
    def context = tomcat.getContext("") //This function does not exist
    context.setSessionCookieDomain(".domain.com")
    context.setSessionCookiePath("/")
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can get this working in both development and production?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

To access the default Tomcat context, you will probably have to patch the TomcatServer's create method in the plugin's TomcatServer.groovy file.

```
TomcatServer(String basedir, String webXml, String contextPath, ClassLoader classLoader) {
    tomcat = new Tomcat()
this.buildSettings = BuildSettingsHolder.getSettings()  

    if(contextPath=='/') contextPath = ''

    def tomcatDir = new File("${buildSettings.projectWorkDir}/tomcat").absolutePath
    def ant = new AntBuilder()      
    ant.delete(dir:tomcatDir, failonerror:false)        

    tomcat.basedir = tomcatDir

    context = tomcat.addWebapp(contextPath, basedir) 
    // ** do additional context stuff here ** 
    tomcat.enableNaming()       

    // we handle reloading manually
    context.reloadable = false
    context.setAltDDName("${buildSettings.projectWorkDir}/resources/web.xml")

    def aliases = []
    def pluginManager = PluginManagerHolder.getPluginManager()
    def pluginSettings = GPU.getPluginBuildSettings()
    if(pluginManager!=null) {
        for(plugin in pluginManager.userPlugins) {
              def dir = pluginSettings.getPluginDirForName(GrailsNameUtils.getScriptName(plugin.name))
              def webappDir = dir ? new File("${dir.file.absolutePath}/web-app") : null
              if (webappDir?.exists())
                    aliases << "/plugins/${plugin.fileSystemName}=${webappDir.absolutePath}"
    }
}

    if(aliases) {
        context.setAliases(aliases.join(','))
    }
    TomcatLoader loader = new TomcatLoader(classLoader)

    loader.container = context
    context.loader = loader

    initialize()
}
```

Comment: Valbuena, The file TomcatServer.groovy is not longer in the plugin. it has been removed when the plugin was upgraded to use Tomcat7 (https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-tomcat-plugin).

Comment: I first tried modifying the tomcat plugin version 1.3.9. But that comes bundled with a version of tomcat where setSessionCookieDomain is not implemented in the StandardContext class. Hence I tried the version 2.0.4, where the TomcatServer class seems to have been removed.